# Two heterozygote mice for skin color are reproduced. Find the probability that in 3 children 2 will be dark and one white

Tags: genetics, gene-expression

Two heterozygote mice for skin color are reproduced. Black is dominant to white color. Find the probability that in 3 children 2 will be dark and one white. How did you do the ordering. Well I found it that in F1: 1/4 are AA, 1/2 Aa, 1/4 aa or 3/4 black and 1/4 white.Now nI think I should multiply the chances: 3/4*1/4*3/4, but it would be according to an order. What should I do? Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you have to keep in mind there are multiple ways to have two dark and one child in a group of three. You have to add the probabilities of each unique outcome that results in two dark and one light child. So, the probability is (1/4) x (3/4) x (3/4) PLUS (3/4) x (1/4) x (3/4) PLUS (3/4) x (3/4) x (1/4)

Comment: Alternatively, multiply one outcome by 3P1.